# Validation of schema, not honored constraints

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a problem with the fact that my schema (which has constraints for fields in form of enums,min and so on, is not being honored when i try to write in the database.I created one object iwth errors but it doesnt say anything and just inserts the wrong data.below is my code: 
recipes.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
        name: {type:String, required:true},     
        category_name: [{ type: String, enum: [ "breakfast", "lunch","dinner"], required:true  }],
        difficulty_level: { type: String, enum: [ 'easy', 'medium', 'hard'], required:true },
        time_of_prep: { type: String, enum: [ '<=30 min', '1h-2h', 'more than 2h'], required:true },
        no_of_servings: { type: Number, min:1 , required:true},    
        ingredients_specified: [{
            ingredient:  {type: String, required:true },
                amount:  {type: String, required:true}
        }], 
        description: {type:String, required:true},
        guide: {type:String, required:true}
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe',schema);
```

recipesSeeder.js:

```
var Recipe = require('../models/recipes');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('pathtodb');
var conn = mongoose.connection;

var recipes=[
    new Recipe({
        name: 'TestName1',
        category_name: 'lunch',
        difficulty_level: 'easy',
        time_of_prep: '<=30min',
        no_of_servings: 5,
        ingredient_specified: {
            ingredient:'banana',
            amount:'2 pieces'
        },
        description: 'description1',
        guide: 'guide1'
    }),
    new Recipe({
        name: ' ',
        category_name: 'testingerrorcat',
        difficulty_level: 'testingerrordiff',
        time_of_prep: 'testingerrortime',
        no_of_servings: 0,
        ingredient_specified: {
            ingredient:'ingredient2',
            amount:'amount2'
        },
        description: 'description2',
        guide: 'guide2'

    }),
    new Recipe({
        name: 'TestName3',
        category_name: 'lunch',
        difficulty_level: 'easy',
        time_of_prep: '<=30min',
        no_of_servings: 5,
        ingredient_specified: {
            ingredient:'ingredient3',
            amount:'amount3'
        },
        description: 'description3',
        guide: 'guide3'
    })
];

var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++){

     conn.collection('recipes2').save(recipes[i]);
     done++;
    if(done === recipes.length){
              console.log('data inserted');
              exit();
           }
}

function exit() {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) validation is a middleware and it is being registered as pre('save') hook on every schema by default. Meaning the validation is applied when you are trying to call save in it, not when initializing. Also you are calling save on conn.collection('recipes2') not on model itself, so there was no validation taking place.

Proper method would be to call the validate function on the model, which returns callback. In the call back check for error, if no error then can call save on model to store into database.

Something like this, I replaced your for-loop with for-each by the way.

```
recipes.forEach(function (recipe) {
    recipe.validate(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);//don't save, do something with the error
            return;
        }
        console.log("validation passsed");
        recipe.save();
    });

});
```

Here is a modification I did to your schema so that it knows which collections it needs to work with.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var schema = new Schema({
         name: {type:String, required:true},     
         category_name: [{ type: String, enum: [ 'breakfast', 'lunch','dinner'], required:true  }],
         difficulty_level: { type: String, enum: [ 'easy', 'medium', 'hard'], required:true },
         time_of_prep: { type: String, enum: [ '<=30min', '1h-2h', 'more than 2h'], required:true },
         no_of_servings: { type: Number, min:1 , required:true},    
         ingredients_specified: [{
             ingredient:  {type: String, required:true },
                 amount:  {type: String, required:true}
         }], 
         description: {type:String, required:true},
         guide: {type:String, required:true}
     });

     module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe',schema, 'recipes2'); //ADDED COLLECTION NAME HERE
```

This being said, after this I encountered minor issue in your schema, you have  '<=30 min' defined, however in your objects you have  '<=30min' with no space. This is a minor issue.

Another issue that I see in your code is that in your for-loop, you are calling save, which is async. Your code will call save but won't wait for it to complete, and simply move on. 
This means you could be done with your entire loop and then call exit function to close the connection, while it hasn't actually saved in the database yet.

I hope it helps.